# How to add image inside the doughnut chart using chart.js?

Tags: angularjs, chart.js

I want to add an image inside the doughnut

[you can see my doughnut here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wknTw.png)

I already tried by using background-image:url(image.png) but is there any way to do it.

Comment: Why are you giving down vote, anyone know the answer or not

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. SO isn't a tutorial website. You should show what you have tried so far in order to encourage users to help you. I suggest you [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and to read about [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Or have a look at [this checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) which is a great reference.

Answer (score 2):

Technically, it's not possible to add images in Charts.

However, you can easily work with that by adding an image as a background for chart container. I.e.:

```
#chartdiv {
  width: 210px;
  height: 210px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: transparent url(YourImage) no-repeat center 70px;
}
```